# how to correct this error "Error redirect_uri_mismatch"?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i use this tutorial https://github.com/anilkumar007/google-login

but when i run my cordova ionic application

I found this error

[image]

Comment: can you explain to me what are you trying to do ? This is an error that occurs when the call back url in your credentials is not the same..

Comment: i want to login in google+ with cordova ionic app

Comment: do you have credentials.json file ?

Comment: no i create the credential with https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: how do you include these credentials in your app ? make sure the redirection urls are the same

Comment: thanks a lot  @MayK its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people walking into this error:

Error: Redirect_uri_mismatch occurs when the redirection uri in your app and in your console / client_secrets.json are not the same.